# Angular Meteor controllerAs getReactively

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

The config function where the controller as is defined:

```
function config($stateProvider){

    $stateProvider
    .state('games', {
        url: '/games',
        templateUrl: 'client/games/games.ng.html',
        controller: 'Games',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    });
}
```

My controller:

```
function GamesController($scope, $meteor, Engine) {
var vm = this;
vm.selectedMove = { _id: 'dsfsdf'}
vm.evaluations = $meteor.collection(Evaluations),
$meteor.subscribe('evaluations', {}, $scope.getReactively('vm.selectedMove')._id).then(function(){
    console.log(vm.evaluations);
});
}
```

I get an error message:
"Cannot read property '_id' of undefined", and it points to this line:
'$scope.getReactively('vm.selectedMove')._id).then...'

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value bound by `$scope.getReactively` may not always be present. In this instance you are calling getReactively while constructing your controller. So `$scope.vm` hasn't been set yet. Hence getReactively will return undefined.

You can try `$scope.getReactively('vm.selectedMove._id')` and check for undefined. For example:

```
this.query = {q : '' };
this.list = $scope.$meteorCollection(Participants);
$scope.$meteorAutorun(function() {
    var q = $scope.getReactively('participants.query.q');
    $scope.$meteorSubscribe('participants', q || '')
});
```

Also note that the whole thing has to be wrapped in autorun.